# What is the minimum number of bytes that should be used to encrypt 4 bytes with AES-128?

Tags: .net, encryption, aes

I am working on a project that involves sending some very small encrypted messages over a high performance socket connection using UDP.  I have read in other posts that the bare minimum number of bytes that AES should encrypt with a 128 bit key is the block size, which is 16 bytes.

But, the real question is - is that enough to provide good protection?  I am thinking about using a scheme that would add some random data to the message and get a random number between 1 and 12 which would be used to place the 4 bytes of real data within the block.  The zero byte in the block would be the random number which is the starting position in the block of the 4 bytes.  After building the block, it would be encrypted with AES using a 128 bit key.  The data does not have any value after the client disconnects, and connections should not last more than 24 - 48 hours at the most.  Will something like this work, or should I send more data to make it harder for a potential adversary to break?

I also will be encrypting other data that does need to be protected after the user disconnects like credit card numbers, bank account info, password hash, etc.  I am planning on using AES with 256 bit keys for that.  So, same question for this case - what is the minimum number of bytes that should be encrypted to provide good protection for 256 bit keys?  Will 16 bytes suffice, or would 32 be better?

I am planning on using bouncy castle's fast AES engine for the small messages.  See:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESFastEngine.html?is-external=true

For the 256 bit AES encryption, I am thinking of using RijndaelManaged since it seems to have better security features on the server and performance is not much of an issue for these infrequent transactions.

Comment: Do you need integrity checking, or just encryption?

Comment: I'm thinking that I might be able to send the last 4 bytes of the random data in the clear as well.  Then, if after decrypting it does not match, then it can be rejected and a request for retransmission can be sent.

Comment: I am thinking that you are trying to create your own protocol, while there are perfectly valid, much more standardized solutions. Creating your own crypto is generally frowned upon. Actually, the more experienced I become, the more I see the dangers of creating my own schemes.

Comment: I am not creating my own crpto solution.  I am using a standard AES library for all encryption.  The reason I am trying to put some random data into the message is to make it harder to break.  What should not be done is to send the the same encrypted block each time a user takes a certain action...  That would be obvious and quite easy to break.  I am coming up with my own protocol using UDP, which is not uncommon.

Comment: Coming up with your own UDP protocol is fine, but e.g. using 4 bytes of random data on a single block may not be OK. Creating a client/server protocol may also be vulnerable to oracle attacks. Instead of thinking about innovative ways of deploying AES, you would be better of to see what's already out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the less cipher text, the less it it susceptible for attacks. It seems you think it is the other way around.

For UDP I would highly recommend to look into counter mode encryption. The advantages is that the key stream can be pre-calculated, which makes for low latency encryption/decryption. It does not require padding either, so you don't have to send more data than required (note that you have a side channel regarding data length, so the difference between "Yes" and "No" can be clearly seen). You do need a good NONCE though.

If you want integrity protection, then GCM mode encryption would be highly advisable. If it is not available, take a look at HMAC or MAC over your cipher text - but you will require two secret keys instead of just the one.

Comment: Have you heard of VMAC?  According to some benchmarks, it looks like it is faster.  Any opinions?

Comment: I have not yet looked into VMAC, sorry. You might ask on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) to get the best possible online advise.

Comment: Was my answer acceptable for you? Sorry if I could not answer the VMAC speed, but that's a separate question.